# Why are Wagmi priority fees on Polygon Mumbai always 50gwei

Tags: ethers.js, polygon, wagmi

I've noticed that all my transactions (see [example](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x152f99590255d4716baf471c46fd36aba2f90abc594d81b425471dc18353c006)) when using wagmi have 50gwei for priority fees in polygon mumbai. Where is this hardcoded value coming from? If wagmi uses ethers behind the scenes, shouldn't the hardcoded value be 1.5 gwei?

Answer (score 0):

Polygon did not implement EIP-1559 in a standard way. Gas calculation is always tricky because of that. Since it's not very expensive, most dev just hardcode a fixed value. You can always change it in metamask before you submit the transaction.